# Getting and setting a three dimensional array

Tags: c++, arrays, image, multidimensional-array

I have to get a three dimensional array c[] w[] h[] from a class and convert it into a single dimensional array of unsigned char[]. I tried this way. But it doesnt work !!.. When I give the input through command line the execution halts and breaks...

Implementation:

```
#include <iostream>
#include<fstream>
#include<stdlib.h>
#include<vector>
//#include "E:\Marvin_To_UnsignedChar\MetisImg.hpp"
//#include "C:\Users\padmanab\Documents\Visual Studio 2013\Projects\Marvin_To_UnsignedChar\MetisImg.hpp"
extern "C"
{
#include "C:\Users\padmanab\Desktop\Marvin_To_UnsignedChar\multiplyImage\multiplyImage.h"
//#include "C:\Users\padmanab\Documents\Visual Studio 2013\Projects\Marvin_To_UnsignedChar\multiplyImage\multiplyImage.h"
}

using namespace std;

class Marvin_To_UnsignedChar
{
public:
    int Color; 
    int Width; 
    int Height;
    std::vector<unsigned char> values;
    Marvin_To_UnsignedChar(int c, int w, int h) : Color(c), Width(w), Height(h), values(c*w*h){}
    unsigned char operator()(int color, int width, int height) const
    {
        return values[Height*Width*color + Height*width + height];
    }
    unsigned char& operator()(int color, int width, int height) 
    {
        return values[Height*Width*color + Height*width + height];
    }
};
```

In Main():

```
int color; int width; int height;
std::cout << "Please enter the color value";
std::cin >> color;
std::cout << "Please enter the width value";
std::cin >> width;
std::cout << "Please enter the height value";
std::cin >> height;


Marvin_To_UnsignedChar M_To_V(color,width,height);
unsigned char test = M_To_V(color, width, height);
std::cout << test << '\n';
```

It would be great to have some guidance about the issue or may be a better method to implement it !

Comment: " When I give the input through command line the execution halts and breaks..." what do you mean by this? What error are you getting?

Comment: `Problem signature:
  Problem Event Name: APPCRASH
  Application Name: Marvin_To_UnsignedChar.exe
  Application Version: 0.0.0.0
  Application Timestamp: 53848d56
  Fault Module Name: Marvin_To_UnsignedChar.exe
  Fault Module Version: 0.0.0.0
  Fault Module Timestamp: 53848d56
  Exception Code: c0000005
  Exception Offset: 0000139a
  OS Version: 6.1.7601.2.1.0.256.48
  Locale ID: 1033
  Additional Information 1: 0a9e
  Additional Information 2: 0a9e372d3b4ad19135b953a78882e789
  Additional Information 3: 0a9e
  Additional Information 4: 0a9e372d3b4ad19135b953a78882e789`

Answer (score 0):

The class code is fine. The problem is that in

```
unsigned char test = M_To_V(color, width, height);
```

you are invoking the `operator()` with the dimensions as parameters (remember that you used before `color`, `width`, `height` to construct the `Marvin_To_UnsignedChar` object), so it will effectively output `values[Color*Width*Height]`, which is one element past the end of the vector. Otherwise the code is fine, you probably want to use something like

```
unsigned char test = M_To_V(x, y, z);
```

where `x, y, z` are such that `x<color, y<width, z<height`.
For example, the code below works (I am initializing in the constructor the array with `'x'` so you can see that something is printed out)

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

using namespace std;

class Marvin_To_UnsignedChar
{
public:
    int Color; 
    int Width; 
    int Height;
    std::vector<unsigned char> values;
    Marvin_To_UnsignedChar(int c, int w, int h) :
            Color(c), Width(w), Height(h), values(c*w*h,'x'){}
    unsigned char operator()(int color, int width, int height) const
    {
        return values.at(Height*Width*color + Height*width + height);
    }
    unsigned char& operator()(int color, int width, int height) 
    {
        return values.at(Height*Width*color + Height*width + height);
    }
};

int main()
{
    int color = 3, width = 777, height = 600;

    Marvin_To_UnsignedChar M_To_V(color,width,height);
    M_To_V(2, 776, 599)='a'; // set the last element to `a`
    std::cout << M_To_V(2, 776, 599) << '\n';
    unsigned char test = M_To_V(1, 200, 300); // this element is pre-initialized with 'x'
    std::cout << test << '\n';
}
```

PS: you can use `values.at(position)` instead of `values[position]` for a `std::vector`, and the former will check for out of bounds, i.e. throw an exception if you get an out of bound, so you can figure out what's going on. The `values[position]` form is faster, but I recommend using `at` at least in debug mode if you are not 100% sure that you may overflow.

Comment: Hi, but the problem is it goes overboard when I give the dimensions like `Color = 3, width = 777, height = 600;` which is the actual dimension in pixels of my image. But it creates same issue with these parameters. I am confused what am I doing wrong here... @vsoftco

Comment: not sure I get it... you can create the array just fine, `Marvin_To_UnsignedChar M_To_V(3, 777, 600);`, then set/get any elements you want, as long you are not getting out of bounds. In `C/C++`, to access an array, let's say defined as `int x[3][4][5];`, each index should be STRICTLY smaller than the dimension, i.e. `x[2][3][4]` is the LAST element, and not `x[3][4][5]` (because of the 0-starting-convention for indices).

Comment: See the modified code, it works just fine, let me know what/where do you get the error. Replace the `[]` with `at()` in `operator()` also, so you may be informed if you are getting out of bounds. Did this in the code above.